# Need Help, Pandas read nested json file

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I was wondering if someone can help me with reading a nested json file like below into a dataframe. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
[
      {
        "cust_batch_id": "1",
        "warning_count": 0,
        "used_vehicles": {
          "used_vehicle_list": [
            {
              "publish_date": "7/30/2021",
              "road_assist_warranty": "5-year/60,000-mile",
              "model_number_list": [
                "K8H"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "template": 4,
         "data_available": true
        }
      },
      {
        "cust_batch_id": "1",
        "warning_count": 0,
        "used_vehicles": {
          "used_vehicle_list": [
            {
              "publish_date": "7/30/2021",
              "road_assist_warranty": "3-year/36,000-mile, ",
              "model_number_list": [
                "FC2F5JEW"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "template": 4,
          "data_available": true
        }
      },
      {
        "cust_batch_id": "1",
        "warning_count": 0,
        "used_vehicles": {
          "used_vehicle_list": [
            {
              "publish_date": "7/30/2021",
              "road_assist_warranty": "5-year/60,000-mile",
              "model_number_list": [
                "P0L"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "template": 4,
          "data_available": true
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

- `js` is the sample JSON you have provided
- simple case of normalize JSON, `explode()` the list, then map embedded **dict** to columns

```
df = pd.json_normalize(js)
df.join(df.loc[:,"used_vehicles.used_vehicle_list"].explode().apply(pd.Series))
```

|  | cust_batch_id | warning_count | used_vehicles.used_vehicle_list | used_vehicles.template | used_vehicles.data_available | publish_date | road_assist_warranty | model_number_list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | [{'publish_date': '7/30/2021', 'road_assist_warranty': '5-year/60,000-mile', 'model_number_list': ['K8H']}] | 4 | True | 7/30/2021 | 5-year/60,000-mile | ['K8H'] |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | [{'publish_date': '7/30/2021', 'road_assist_warranty': '3-year/36,000-mile, ', 'model_number_list': ['FC2F5JEW']}] | 4 | True | 7/30/2021 | 3-year/36,000-mile, | ['FC2F5JEW'] |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | [{'publish_date': '7/30/2021', 'road_assist_warranty': '5-year/60,000-mile', 'model_number_list': ['P0L']}] | 4 | True | 7/30/2021 | 5-year/60,000-mile | ['P0L'] |

#### prerequisites

- how to save JSON to a file and how to load JSON from a file
- this is your sample JSON
- you can also decode JSON encoded in a string with `json.loads(str)`

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

js = [{'cust_batch_id': '1',
  'warning_count': 0,
  'used_vehicles': {'used_vehicle_list': [{'publish_date': '7/30/2021',
     'road_assist_warranty': '5-year/60,000-mile',
     'model_number_list': ['K8H']}],
   'template': 4,
   'data_available': True}},
 {'cust_batch_id': '1',
  'warning_count': 0,
  'used_vehicles': {'used_vehicle_list': [{'publish_date': '7/30/2021',
     'road_assist_warranty': '3-year/36,000-mile, ',
     'model_number_list': ['FC2F5JEW']}],
   'template': 4,
   'data_available': True}},
 {'cust_batch_id': '1',
  'warning_count': 0,
  'used_vehicles': {'used_vehicle_list': [{'publish_date': '7/30/2021',
     'road_assist_warranty': '5-year/60,000-mile',
     'model_number_list': ['P0L']}],
   'template': 4,
   'data_available': True}}]

fn = Path.cwd().joinpath("SO_js.json")
# save to a file
with open(fn, "w") as f: json.dump(js, f)
# load from a file
with open(fn) as f: js = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob for your help. I'm not familiar with JSON. I tried to read the inputs into JSON object a couple of ways. None worked. Can you please show your step in which you put the samples into the js? Thank you!

Comment: I've pasted more into answer.  I don't know where you sourced JSON from, quite commonly an API using **requests** package.  That has a build in method `json()`

Comment: Rob, Thank you!

Comment: Just to add, reading this type of data is not my job. So I'm pretty sure that I'm not doing the way it is designed to.